# Can I change foreground color of disabled swt control

Tags: java, swt

I need to set the foreground color of disabled controls to black instead of that grey. I see that the background color can be set but i couldn't set the foreground color. Is it posible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is very important, you might be able to paint the text yourself by hooking into the paint event... I haven't tried though :-)

Answer (score 2):

Depends on which control you want to change back/foreground. In [SWT Javadoc the setBackgroundColor method](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Control.html#setBackground%28org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color%29) you can find this note

`Note: This operation is a hint and may be overridden by the platform. For example, on Windows the background of a Button cannot be changed.`